# If Time is less than 10 show "00", "01", "02"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show `if time is less than 10 hours or minute or seconds` then, it time will show like `"00", "01", "02","03"...` but right now it showing `"0", "1", "2", "3"...`

CODE:

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
  <div id="label"></div>
</body>
```

check seconds

Answer (score 2):

this help you :

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    <body onload="startTime()">
        <div id="label"></div>
     <script>
         function startTime() {
             var today = new Date();
             var h = today.getHours();
             var m = today.getMinutes();
             var s = today.getSeconds();
             if (h < 10 ) { h = "0" + h;}
             if (m < 10 ) {m = "0" + m;}
             if (s < 10 ) {s = "0" + s;}      
             document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
             var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
         }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or use this code :

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
    <body onload="startTime()">
       <div id="label"></div>
        <script>
           function startTime() {
               var today = new Date();
               var h = today.getHours();
               var m = today.getMinutes();
               var s = today.getSeconds();
                h = (h < 10 ) ? ("0" + h) : h;
                m = (m < 10 ) ? ("0" + m) : m;
                s = (s < 10 ) ? ("0" + s) : s;               
                document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
                var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
           }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: script after body? Is it legal? =)

Comment: my post is edited , tank you @vp_arth.

Answer (score 1):

Do something tricky with **[`String#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** method

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = ('0' + h).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + m).slice(-2) + ":" + ('0' + s).slice(-2);
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
```

```html
<body onload="startTime()">
  <div id="label"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  //====Add this=======
    if(h<10){ h = '0' + h; }
    if(m<10){ m = '0' + m; }
    if(s<10){ s = '0' + s; }
  //===================
  document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pad (str) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < 2 ? "0" + str : str;
}
```

Simply use this function for hours, minutes whatever.

```
h = pad(h);
m = pad(m);
s = pad(s);
```